# Cross Compiling problems with nestled CMakelists.txt files

Tags: cmake, makefile, cross-compiling, intel, target

I do need to include "Cross Compiling" in my project (Intel and PowerPC) and I have found a problem defining targets. I have the following folder structure:

libs

- *.h
- *.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt

src

- *.h
- *.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt

...

-CMakeLists.txt

If a write the following piece of code in the CMakeLists.txt of the src folder, It works ...

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE( intel ${SOURCES} ) SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES( intel PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${APP_NAME}_INTEL EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL true ) TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( intel ${LIBS_INTEL}  )
```

However I don't really know how to do it in the CMakeLists of the libraries (libs folder). If I follow the same structure and use "intel" as a target, it returns an error message saying that "the target name is already used".

I do want to compile all my project with both options:

"make intel" --> to generate Intel version and "make powerPc" --> to generate PowerPC version

I have been looking for it on the Internet but I couldn't find a correct solution.

I hope anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. It was as easy as using the following macro in the main CMakeLists.txt file.

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET ( INTEL DEPENDS EXECUTABLE1 EXECUTABLE2 ... EXECUTABLEN)

And the same with the other target powerpc.